# How to list all files on Windows OS partition from a Linux OS?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, partitioning, fedora

I have Windows and Fedora Linux on dual boot in my laptop.

There are files on my Windows OS that seem to be hidden ...
I know Linux can see EVERYTHING on a Windows disk partition.

How can I list, from my Fedora environment, ALL files in a specific NTFS partition ? Also, how can I filter the results in descending order of size and date of creation/modification of the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Mount the Windows parrtition.
2. Use [*ls*](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/ls.htm) to list files. -R shows files recursively, -a shows *all* files, -t sorts by date-time, -S by size. Pipe the output to a file to avoid looking at *many* screens.

Answer (score 0):

install Midnight Commander https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander (package name mc) to see all files by default.